# Why rectangle packing is NP-hard but maybe not in NP?

Tags: np-hard, np, decision-problem

Recently I studied a [MIT open course](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-890-algorithmic-lower-bounds-fun-with-hardness-proofs-fall-2014/resources/mit6_890f14_lec2/).

In [lecture2](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-890-algorithmic-lower-bounds-fun-with-hardness-proofs-fall-2014/2c3913aefe7be0f98fcc16394ef6ea4b_MIT6_890F14_Lec2.pdf), it is stated that Rectangle Packing is NP-hard.

I can understand this because the problem can be reduced to [3-partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem)

**But I don't know why it's an open problem whether it's in NP.**

In lecture2 it is stated that:

> it is complicated to encode rotations efficiently.

**My question:**
How to understand the last sentence?

[image]

Comment: NP definitely doesn't include all decision problems. Only those than can be solved in polynomial-time by a nondeterministc Turing machine.

Comment: Oh thank you very much, but how can i understand the last sentence.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In order for a language $L$ to be in NP, there needs to be a way to certify that instance $x$ belongs to $L$. This "way" is a polynomial size witness which can be verified in polynomial time.

In this case, the obvious witness is a packing of the rectangles. Given such a packing, it is easy to check that it is indeed a packing. What is less clear is whether the witness has polynomial size, since it is not clear how to encode the rotations succinctly (or at all).

Comment: Thank you very much, the main reason is the arbitary rotation right? What if we restrict the minim rotation angle, and any rotation must be multiple of minimum rotation angle. Is it NP in this situation?

Comment: If you change the problem so that it has a polynomial size certificate which can be verified in polynomial time, then it is in NP.

Comment: Couldn't the rotation and translation be described by a transformation $Ax = b$, where $A$ is a rotation matrix (easy to verify) and $b$ is a translation vector? Then you need only $6n$ numbers for each rectangle. Or is the issue that the rotation matrix may include irrational numbers?

Comment: That’s a question to the person who wrote the lecture notes. I don’t know anything about this particular problem.

Comment: @Max
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.06969.pdf
Understanding the class $\exists \mathbb{R}$, and hard problems for this class could help.

Comment: @Max The numbers could be irrational numbers, or perhaps arbitrarily complicated ratios. Who says they are a polynomial number of bits long?

Comment: @Max Actually, since you specified a rotation matrix, in almost all cases 4n of the 6n numbers would be irrational with your idea - infinity bits long. How do you verify infinity bits in finite time?

Comment: Right, the issue is that membership in NP requires the certificate to be a polynomial number of **bits** long. Real numbers cannot in general be encoded in a finite number of bits, and actual rectangle packings tend to get some weird angles. The problem is in $\exists \mathbb R$ but may not be in NP.